# How to put a label to an object in CoppeliaSim

Tags: simulator, robotics

I want to add a label to a shape in Coppelia.

I read about using a simSetObjectName(), but it does not appear in the RegularAPI documentation.
I read also about banners, but I do not find neither documentation about it.

Can you tell me please what to use in 2023.

For what I need, a Banner or something similar will work better than a renaming.

Thanks.

I already tried searching in the RegularAPI documentation. Please do not use simx functions because I am using a newer client. :)

I want to have like a little post-it or label attached to the object.